# Universal Sentence Encoder embed runtime error: resource exhausted by allocator CPU

Tags: tensorflow, runtime-error, tensorflow-hub

Give the following code:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_eager_execution()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  embed=hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")
  sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
  sess.run(embed(["test message"]))
```

I was successfully able to run it on a local Ubuntu machine CPU i5 and 3 GB of RAM, however when I try to run it on a VPS centOS with 4GB RAM and uname details: Linux 2.6.32-042stab141.3 MSK 2019 x86_64, I get the following error:

```
 2020-06-19 14:15:10.612770: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1753] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[26667,320] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)

  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1349, in _run_fn
    return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1441, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[26667,320] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu         [[{{node RestoreV2}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testEncoder.py", line 12, in <module>
    get_features(["one message"])
  File "testEncoder.py", line 5, in get_features
    sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 957, in run
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1180, in _run
    results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1358, in _do_run
    return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[26667,320] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
         [[node RestoreV2 (defined at /home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module_v2.py:102) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
Original stack trace for 'RestoreV2':
  File "testEncoder.py", line 10, in <module>
    embed=hub.load("universal_sentence_encoder")
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module_v2.py", line 102, in load
    obj = tf_v1.saved_model.load_v2(module_path, tags=tags)
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 578, in load
    return load_internal(export_dir, tags)
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 602, in load_internal
    loader = loader_cls(object_graph_proto,
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._restore_checkpoint()
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 310, in _restore_checkpoint
    load_status = saver.restore(variables_path)
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py", line 1303, in restore
    base.CheckpointPosition(
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 209, in restore
    restore_ops = trackable._restore_from_checkpoint_position(self)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 906, in _restore_from_checkpoint_position
    current_position.checkpoint.restore_saveables(
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py", line 288, in restore_saveables
    new_restore_ops = functional_saver.MultiDeviceSaver(
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py", line 281, in restore
    restore_ops.update(saver.restore(file_prefix))
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py", line 95, in restore
    restored_tensors = io_ops.restore_v2(
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1503, in restore_v2
    _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 742, in _apply_op_helper
    op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3319, in _create_op_internal
    ret = Operation(
  File "/home/userM/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1791, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

I read that clearing the session after training the model using tf.keras.backend.clear_session() can be a fix, but it's not actually because it's not the case.
Any idea what could cause this error? and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: apparently the main issue that lead to this error is: Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

Can tensorflow run on server without NVIDIA devices?

Comment: Hi. When and Where are you getting the error, `Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:`? Yes Tensorflow Runs on Server without NVIDIA Devices but for that to work, you should install `Tensorflow`, not `Tensorflow-gpu`. Can you please let us know if you are trying to install `Tensorflow` or `Tensorflow-gpu`? Thanks!

Comment: The error is raised when i try to execute the embed(["test message"]). I have installed Tensorflow not tensorflow-gpu. The error is shown on CentOs only. It's working just fine on ubuntu 16 with the same packages installed